# how to extract urls using python, html.parser, and regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a program in Python that parses all the URLs from a .html file and prints out all the tags and links like so:

```
meta: https://someurl.com
a: https://someurl.com
link: css/bootstrap.min.css
script: https://somescript.js
```

Currently, what I have is

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re

class HeadParser(HTMLParser):

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    #use re.findall to get all the links
    links = re.findall("http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\), ]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+", website)
    for url in links:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(tag, url))

website = open("./head.html").read()            
HeadParser().feed(website)
```

and it returns to me

```
head: https://scooptacular.net
head: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/379d05029c0d84618c70ac037a25fd88.jpg
head: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/4baaa58a1a37fd3da3e4e78caf366b7f.jpg
head: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700
head: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
head: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
head: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
head: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js
head: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js
meta: https://scooptacular.net
meta: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/379d05029c0d84618c70ac037a25fd88.jpg
meta: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/4baaa58a1a37fd3da3e4e78caf366b7f.jpg
meta: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700
meta: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
meta: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
meta: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
meta: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js
meta: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js
meta: https://scooptacular.net
meta: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/379d05029c0d84618c70
```

As you can see, it returns me a link for every tag, even duplicates, and does not return any local file links. What is wrong with my code?

EDIT:

the html i'm using is:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://scooptacular.net" />    
<meta property="og:image" content="https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/379d05029c0d84618c70ac037a25fd88.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/4baaa58a1a37fd3da3e4e78caf366b7f.jpg" />

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<link href="css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting what you want – *all* the urls. The duplicates may just occur more than once in that web page. Which are the ones that you did not expect?

Comment: it makes no sense to have a link inside of a "head" tag (there is no such thing as <head href="">) so why is it printing it out?

Comment: you can use `set(links)` to remove to duplicates,also you are clearly getting the first tag it runs to,what you want is the tag inside `<head`

Comment: Can you post an example of links that you're handling? Right now, i did __http(|s):[^\'$\s]+__ and seems to work (it gets all links there, but lets try something more general) Note: I assume all links starts with http or https.
https://regex101.com/r/h1Y8Cu

Comment: @lucas_7_94 i edited the post to include the links i'm handling. not all links start with http/s

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that `handle_starttag` is called for every tag, and with each call you're searching the *entire* page for matches to your regex, not just the tag you're on (the second argument you're passing to `re.findall` is `website`).

I don't see why you need to use regular expressions at all here. Why not just rely on whether or not the tag has an `href`, `src` or `content` attribute:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class HeadParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        for attr in attrs:
            if attr[0] in ['href', 'src', 'content']:
                print('{0}: {1}'.format(tag, attr[1]))


website = open("./head.html").read()
HeadParser().feed(website)
```

Output:

```
meta: https://scooptacular.net
meta: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/379d05029c0d84618c70ac037a25fd88.jpg
meta: https://scooptacular.net/img/uploaded/4baaa58a1a37fd3da3e4e78caf366b7f.jpg
link: css/bootstrap.min.css
link: css/agency.css
link: font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
link: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700
link: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script
link: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic
link: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700
link: css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css
script: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js
script: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js
```